# Select folder dialog on android?

Tags: android, directory, filepicker

Is there some 'select folder dialog' on android SDK ? 
I google it and i did not find anything.

I mean that i looking for dialog that will popup and give me the option to select a path of folder (  like select file dialog ... but the return argument will be full path of a folder )

Its hard to believe that on this marvelous sdk there is no way to select full folder path.

Any help please ..

thanks.

Comment: but can u explain more about your requirement buddy, Unable to understand?

Comment: add more explain embedded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21544368/4044380

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public void performFileSearch() {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
   startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Or If you using samsung phone, You can call Intent.

```
//Samsung Device
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");
    intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

[providers/document-provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)

This link will be help for you

Comment: As OP is asking to select a folder you should have told about ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE instead ;-). Yours is for selecting a file.

Comment: You made a big mesh out of it now.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this library to do the same:
https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser